# WYSIWYG Editor not saving typed or pasted text

Tags: cms, static-block, wysiwyg

We started a new build and are roughly 80 hours into it. When we type or paste content into the editor it will not save.  Is there something I can edit to check sensitivity? Is it a db issue?

Comment: does it work if you disable the editor and enable it again after pasting something into it?

Comment: I will check now.

Comment: The only resolution Im seeing so far is that whatever text editor the customer used added some sort of meta data. If I type directly now it works. It also worked from openoffice.

Comment: Could be wrong HTML, afaik it is stripped or removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that it was some sort of meta data. We pulled it from a customer supplied document.